# Laravel breeze install don't have the typescript option

Tags: react-typescript, laravel-breeze

I'm using the command `php artisan breeze:install` to install the react version. But the questions asked are only:

- Which stack would you like to install?
- Would you like to install dark mode support?
- Would you like to install Inertia SSR support?

There is not question for use of typescript even the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia) saying:

> When selecting the Vue or React frontend stack, the Breeze installer will also prompt you to determine if you would like Inertia SSR or **TypeScript support**.

I'm using the laravel/breeze in the 1.19.2 version.

I tries use `php artisan breeze:install` with the option for React, no darkmode and no ssr.